# How do i solve CPLEX with Java : Infeasibility row 'c2': 0 = -3

Tags: java, cplex

i try to solve the LP but it can't not solve it...

The problem is if i have six area need to be dispatched some people to there to build the house. In six area have some sub-area for each other, each sub area have different cost and one sub-area only need one person, but all of sub area have one person in one area that i can used.

for example:

i have five people can dispatch

Area
A1--->3 sub area : A11,A12,A13

A2--->3 sub area : A21,A22,A23

A3--->3 sub area : A31,A32,A33

A4--->3 sub area : A41,A42,A43

A5--->3 sub area : A51,A52,A53

A6--->3 sub area : A61,A62,A63

now i used the cplex to choose the min cost to dispatch the people, if i assume A1 have the min cost, so i dispatch three people to the A11,A12,A13.

then i remain two people can dispatch, but no any area have two sub area, so i can not dispatch any more.

with this code

```
double[][] A = new double[6][];
A[0] = new double[3];
A[1] = new double[3];
A[2] = new double[3];
A[3] = new double[3];
A[4] = new double[3];
A[5] = new double[3];

//cost of sub area
A[0][0] = 999;
A[0][1] = 397;
A[0][2] = 698;

A[1][0] = 1717;
A[1][1] = 1147;
A[1][2] = 1192;

A[2][0] = 1752;
A[2][1] = 1154;
A[2][2] = 1453;

A[3][0] = 2059;
A[3][1] = 1528;
A[3][2] = 1788;

A[4][0] = 601;
A[4][1] = 270;
A[4][2] = 357;

A[5][0] = 1113;
A[5][1] = 815;
A[5][2] = 928;


// x for decision variable, if I dispatch person to sub area x = 1.
IloNumVar[][] x = new IloNumVar[6][];

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    x[i] = cplex.boolVarArray(A[i].length);

}



 IloLinearNumExpr numExpr_total = cplex.linearNumExpr();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        IloLinearNumExpr numExpr = cplex.linearNumExpr();           

        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {

            numExpr.addTerm(1.0, x[i][j]);

            numExpr_total.addTerm(1.0, x[i][j]);

       }

       cplex.addEq(numExpr, A[i].length);           
       cplex.addLe(numExpr_total, peopleNum);

    }

    loLinearNumExpr object = cplex.linearNumExpr();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {

             object.addTerm(A[i][j], x[i][j]);

        }

    }

cplex.addMaximize(object);
```

so when i execute the program, i show the error

CPXPARAM_Read_APIEncoding                        "UTF8"

Infeasibility row 'c2':  0  = -3.

Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.01 ticks)

how can i fix it?

Comment: Often, a good way to debug Cplex code is to write out the LP file and see what model is actually being generated.

Comment: The way you've defined your problem, some of the variables are forced to be zero, but you are making the sum be equal to 3. The easiest way for you to debug is for you to write out the LP to a text file using `IloCplex.exportmodel()`

Comment: i used cplex.exportModel("lpex1.lp") , and it show ->
Default variable names x1, x2 ... being created.
Default row names c1, c2 ... being created. whats that mean?

Answer (score 1):

As Erwin said, examining the .lp file of your model is usually the best way to start debugging. However, it frequently happened to me that the root cause(s) of infeasible rows were not obvious due to several other buggy constraints or bounds being involved. In those cases, CPLEX provides a 'conflict refiner' which helps you narrowing down the potential causal model members. [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21437987) is how you invoke the tool using JAVA API.

Comment: Okay, i'll try to fix it. Thank you for your reply!